# Smart Notebook v11 does not work correctly after I updated to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have Smart Notebook v11 software (for Smartboard) and when I plug into a projector it will not display the entire screen and it is frozen.

The original slide is the only slide that displays.

Comment: What exactly is Smart 11? Do you have a link? The name of the manufacturer? The exact name of the software?

Comment: Smart Notebook 11 (for the smartboard)

Comment: I have personally used `Smart Notebook 11` in the past on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 machines.  Have you confirmed that `Smart Notebook 11` supports Windows 10.  Having personal experience with `Smart Notebook 11`, and the horrible experience that is, I know you the version you are using isn't supported by Windows 10 nor is it supported by the company.

Answer (score 2):

#### SMART Notebook Version 11 does not work correctly with WIndows 10.

The latest version is SMART Notebook 15.1.

It is not surprising that an old version (Version 11 was released on October 2, 2012) does not work with a new operating system.

You should upgrade to the latest version 15.1 (which added support for Windows 10).

You can also contact [SMART support](http://smarttech.com/Home%20Page/Support/Regional%20Contact) for their advice.

---

#### SMART Notebook 15.1 - Windows 10 support

We can now confirm that following testing, SMART have stated that SMART Notebook 15.1 will be supported for use with Windows 10.

Please be mindful that Microsoft is releasing updates regularly, so it is always possible that minor instabilities could arise as the operating system evolves too (as would be the case with any software).

Source [Latest Release Smart Notebook 15.1 Software up-dates](http://blog.tecinteractive.co.uk/latestreleasesmartnotebook15.1softwareup-dates)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Due to the software being highly reliant on the display capabilities of the operating system, and with the WDDM being updated with Windows 10, its highly likely there is an underlined incompatibility in the version the author is using.